# In MVC, do I only need Models when using ORM?

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller

I am developing an web app and want to interact with my database using raw SQL (T-SQL, stored procedures etc) without ORM.

I was under the impression that when using MVC, all database interactions would be in a Model file like `products.js` which has various functions for Products like `getAllProducts()`. However after reading [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Displaying_data/Book_list_page) it seems that a Model is an ORM representation of a table in a database and it is a Controller file that does all the database interaction (i.e. selecting from model).

So if I am developing without ORM, what do I require a Model for in an MVC development pattern? Do I just skip using a Model and put everything in my Controller files? Or is it something in-between?

Comment: *"and put everything in my Controller files"* -- the controller should not contain processing. The tutorial you mention puts in the controller code that should not stay there. It is a bad tutorial, if you ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can still create model objects and use them to pass data around within your application or to other applications interacting with your application.

[MVC :: What is a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221632/mvc-what-is-a-model)